# Asymptote: Prevent Scientific Notation on Tick Labels

Tags: asymptote

I have a graph whose x-axis goes from 2000 to 10,000. Unfortunately, the tick labels are "2000" on one end and "1 X 10<sup>4</sup>" on the other. How can I avoid or prevent this?

I tried giving an explicit list of Ticks to LeftTicks. My current axis code is:

```
import fontsize;
import graph;
// ...
defaultpen(fontsize(7));
real[] graph_ticks={2000,6000,10000};
xaxis("Mean (ms)" ,BottomTop,LeftTicks(Ticks=graph_ticks));
yaxis("Probability",LeftRight,RightTicks(trailingzero));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Format parameter of the [LeftTicks (or RightTicks) method](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/graph.html#ticks) to specify a [C-style format string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/). "%f" will give regular decimal floating point:

```
defaultpen(fontsize(7)); // requires import fontsize;
real[] graph_ticks={2000,6000,10000};
xaxis("Mean (ms)",BottomTop,LeftTicks(Format="%f",Ticks=graph_ticks));
yaxis("Probability",LeftRight,RightTicks(trailingzero));
```

As it happens, `trailingzero` seems to be a special sort of format string in Asymptote. "%" will allow you to suppress tick labels altogether.